# I can't get Webrick server to run on windows 10 64bit system. Ruby 2.2.2p95 and Rails 4.2.3 but are 32bit version

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I can't get Webrick server to run on windows 10 64bit system. Ruby 2.2.2p95 and Rails 4.2.3 but are 32bit version:

```
C:\Users\Sher\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:7:in `<class:Template>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:6:in `<module:WebConsole>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Sher/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

C:\Users\Sher\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>

Comment: I am new to the ruby on rails world and I am stuck at this point I am hoping someone can help me please. I am not sure what is causing this error because I went through all the steps without a problem. 1. ruby installer 2. devkit 3. ruby gems packager 4. rails installer 5. mysql database 6. mysql ruby gem.  and created my project and when i try to run webrick server then i get the error.

Answer (score 0):

`actionpack 4.2` needs `rack ~> 1.6.0`. 
Your Gemfile probably does not include `rack` gem.

You can try adding this line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rack', '~> 1.6.0'
```

and then run:

```
bundle install
```

see if that fixes your problem!

Comment: thank you K M Rakilbul  for your suggestion I really appreciate the support. I did what you said however when I run the command " rails server" I still get the error. any other suggestion we could try?

Comment: I'm not sure where to past it on here

Comment: should I ask another question to past it in?

Comment: No, you can just edit your current question and add additional information.

Comment: thanks I was trying to do it earlier however I don't have enough rep to post more than two links. can i email the file to you?

Comment: do you have this project on github? then send me the link. I will try it locally and see where is the problem.

Comment: no I don't have it up on github. the thing is I am trying to get my feet wet in the world of web apps, I do have a github account but only recently so I am not sure how it really works. total noob to github

Comment: ok I am going to set it up and link to you ok whats your user name on github

Comment: my github: rakibulislam
send me the link and add me as a collaborator so that I can clone and push.